# How to subset data based on inputs from renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, renderui

I am trying to subset my data based on inputs from `renderUI`. This data would then be passed to further work in an `observe` chunk.

Below is an example, where there is an issue with the server code. I am having difficulties with the code recognising the input to an `if` clause - or more accurately it starts of `NULL` and then `"Every row"` from the `input` is recognised.  If I uncomment `carbData()` in `observe` below I get the following error. Also receive a similar error if I move the subset inside the `observe` environment.

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7400
> NULL  ### from check()
> Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
> 61: reactive:carbData [#9]
> 45: carbData
> 44:  [#17]
> 1: runApp

Is this due to some delayed evaluation from using `renderUI`? If so, or otherwise how do I fix it please?

My code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    amData <- reactive({ mtcars[am %in% input$am, ] }) 
    output$gear <- renderUI({ selectInput("Gear", "GEAR", 
                                choices=unique(amData()[, "gear"]), selected=4 ) })
    
    gearData <- reactive({ amData()[gear %in% input$Gear, ] }) 
    output$carb <- renderUI({ selectInput("Carb", "CARB", 
                                choices=c("Every row", unique(gearData()[, "carb"])), selected="Every row") })
    
    carbData <-  reactive({ if(input$Carb %in% "Every row") gearData() else gearData()[ carb %in% input$Carb ] }) #### PROBLEM
    
    # Some text where it can be seen that input$Carb  is initially NULL
    check <-  reactive({ p <- input$Carb; print(p) }) 
    
    observe({ 
      check(); 
        
      # problems with if clause in both of these:
      # carbData() 
        
      # Moving the data subset inside `observe` doesn't help
      # df <- if(input$Carb %in% "Every row") gearData() else gearData()[ carb %in% input$Carb ]
      })
}
```

And the rest of the code to allow it to run:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data(mtcars); data.table::setDT(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
   sidebarMenu(
       selectInput("am", "AM", unique(mtcars$am), selected = "0"),
       uiOutput("gear"),
       uiOutput("carb")
       )),
  dashboardBody())

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Try with adding `req(input$Carb)` at the beginning of your reactive `CarbData`, just before the `if`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I don't think I added it quite where you suggested, but using `if(req(input$Carb) %in% "Every row")` seems to do the trick

Comment: Okay. I meant to put it here: `carbData <-  reactive({ req(input$Carb); ....`. As far as I get it the issue is that your UI is rendered only after the first call to CarbData().

Comment: Thanks . I don't really get why `gear %in% input$Gear` allows it to render fine but  `input$Carb %in% "Every row"` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit uncertain whether this question is closed. However, I took the luxury of editing your codes to locate the problem.

I used `tibbles` instead of `data.table` as I am not familiar with the syntax. So far @stefan is absolutely correct, `req(input$Carb)` will relieve you of your troubles.

The reason that `gear %in% input$Gear` works, and `input$Carb %in% "Every row"` does not, is that the `reactive`-hierachy does not favor `input$Carb`, and as it is `null` at startup, you are essentially testing `NULL %in% "Every Row"`. Where as `gear` exists by construction at app start up.

This is not, as Im certain that you are aware of, the same as `input$Carb %in% "NULL"`, or `NULL` for that matter.

This is your code that I played around with,

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        amData <- reactive({
                mtcars %>% filter(am %in% input$am)
                
                
        })
        
        gearData <- reactive({
                amData() %>% filter(gear %in% input$Gear)
                
                
        })
        
        
        output$gear <- renderUI({
                selectInput("Gear",
                            "GEAR",
                            choices = unique(amData()[, "gear"]),
                            selected = 4)
        })
        
        
        output$carb <- renderUI({
                selectInput(
                        "Carb",
                        "CARB",
                        choices = c("Every row", unique(gearData()[, "carb"])),
                        selected = "Every row"
                )
        })
        
        carbData <-
                reactive({
                        
                        req(input$Carb)
                        
                        if (input$Carb %in% "Every row")
                                gearData()
                        else
                                gearData() %>% filter(carb %in% input$Carb)
                }) #### PROBLEM
        
        # Some text where it can be seen that input$Carb  is initially NULL
        check <-  reactive({
                p <- input$Carb
                print(p)
        })
        
        observe({
                check()
                
                
                # problems with if clause in both of these:
                carbData()
                
        })
}
```